# Gmail API ID is not working but and thread ID is working

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

When I was querying to Gmail API

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',q="from:xyz@wso2.com", maxResults=10).execute()
```

I got this output. Here I don't get every messages It's only returned the `Thread Id` and the `id`

```
"messages": [
  {
   "id": "1655b9b497dc76aa",
   "threadId": "165380da74833127"
  },
  {
   "id": "1655b9a7409383dd",
   "threadId": "1655b9a7409383dd"
  },
  {
   "id": "1655b9a25c441268",
   "threadId": "16470b77316be7ab"
  },
  {....
```

In order to get the messages, I have to query again. The problem here is When I querying using Id it's returning the 400 error but when I use threaded it's returning the message with a snippet. But in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get), they have clearly mentioned that we have to give the id

```
id -    string  - The ID of the message to retrieve.
```

1. What's the difference between Thread Id and Id?
2. Can't I query all the fields-

> "labelIds": [
>         "UNREAD",
>         "CATEGORY_FORUMS",
>         "INBOX"
>        ],
>        "snippet": "Hi Amanda, Ruwan and Mifan, We've got through to the RFP round with Verizon! Could you please review the RFP and start
>   working on this? Let me know if we need to get WSO2 Telco involved.
>   Thanks,",
>        "historyId": "5217959",
>        "internalDate": "1534833021000"....

as a JSON without querying, again and again, using every Id? It seems Google API may block me using throttling mechanism If I query that much of time since I have to query 150000 ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [Message resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) for which one is returned for each message in the response.

> id string  The immutable ID of the message.
>
> threadId   string  The ID of the thread the message belongs to. To add a message or draft to a thread, the following criteria must be met:
>
> - The requested threadId must be specified on the Message or Draft.Message you supply with your request.
> - The References and In-Reply-To headers must be set in compliance with the RFC 2822 standard.
>     -The Subject headers must match.

You cant do a [message.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) on a message.threadid message.get requires a message.id

> Can't I query all the messages as a JSON without querying, again and again, using every Id? It seems Google API may block me using throttling mechanism If I query that much of time since I have to query 150000 ids.

No there is a limit on the maxResults that can be returned.  I think its around 100 but i am not seeing it documented.   You are going to have to use the nextPageToken returned in the request to get the next page of results.   There is a limit to how fast you can make requests.  So keep things reasonable or you will be throttled.

**Update in response to question edit**

> Can't I query all the fields-

If you run the following using `fields=*` [Doc on fields paramater](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/query-parameters)

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',q="from:xyz@wso2.com", maxResults=10,fields=*).execute()
```

You will notices the response is the same

```
   {
   "id": "1655bb6d0f2b5f8f",
   "threadId": "1655bb6d0f2b5f8f"
    },
```

That is all the fields in the response of a files.list. If you want more information you must do a [message.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)

**Gmail quota**

The quota is large for Gmail for this reason.  Most of them can also be extended.

[image]

Comment: "You cant do a message.get on a thread id message.get requires a message.id " but try it it is not working .  what they have mentioned ID is as threadid @DalmTo https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Comment: @Sathiyakugan As you have edited your question I have now updated my answer.

Comment: So even I get the 100 id's at the one query inorder to get those fields I have to query again 100 times isn't it ?

Comment: Basically.  Welcome to the annoying world of Gmail api development :(

Comment: Top tip:  If you need to apply for an extension of your quota do it early when you are at like 80% of the quota you have it can take a month to get approved.